# Ergonomic rules for repetitive handling of wood pieces

Tags: ergonomics

ok, I hope to be clear in my question for my first one on this SE site.

I'm trying to design a trolley divided in several compartments.

Each compartment will correspond to a set of wood pieces. These pieces are cleats (not sure of the english translation for that: I mean long pieces with small section) of wood with a section of about 100x100 millimeters and which are up to 3 meters long. And the trolley is designed so that the wood pieces are placed vertically.

These pieces of wood are produced (cut) by a machine which delivers each of them about every 20 seconds.

From the machine output (a conveyor, so the pieces of wood lay at the horizontal) to the trolley, the pieces of wood are handled by a human person.

The question is:

What are the ergonomic rules (or studies for this situation...), about taking a long piece of wood which lays horizontally, by a human person, at around 1 meter up on the convoyer, to some location where this piece of wood will be placed vertically. So that, the pieces of wood will need to be rotated from horizontal to vertical by the person?

Edit:

Here is the context. A convoyer which carries pieces of wood. And in front of it the trolley with several locations.

The question is about: is, for a human, acceptable to take the pieces of wood from the conveyor and bear/rotate them to the trolley?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about woodworking and not about workplace.

Comment: @Ertai87, well, as said I'm new here. My question is about ergonomy, not wood working in itself. But in a workplace if it is ergonomically acceptable to handle pieces of wood... acceptable on this site? If not please be fair enough to drive me to other SE site. Thank you.

Comment: You are asking for the ergonomic "rules"... Rules established by whom? According to what standards? According to what preferences? ... what have you found so far regarding possible "rules" or "standards" so we can suggest alternatives (otherwise this reads a bit like "please google the rules for me")?

Comment: Suggestion: Perhaps a drawing or image would help understand better what you describe

Comment: @DarkCygnus, well, medical studies, about repetitive movements. If not why is there a "ergonomic" tag here?

Comment: I would redesign the machinery; it's trivial to add a stationary ramp to the end of the conveyor that could turn a long piece of wood through 90 degrees and drop it into a trolley. All the operator would then have to do is locate the wood within the trolley.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of the tag. However, as you just mentioned, seems you are seeking for medical studies, etc. regarding ergonomics. That is something that you could google and find out, or something you could learn by reading papers and similar. As you can see, it's quite broad (and more asking for sources rather than answers from experts). I think that if you narrow it down (perhaps, by including an image, and asking what can be improved from your design in terms of ergonomics) your post will be more answerable.

Comment: Guys, question updated with an image to illustrate the context.

Comment: Welcome to Workplace, and thank you for your effort to craft a good question. It is indeed a good question. But, with respect, we should not be your only source to ask such technical questions about workplace safety.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you. This is always difficult to know if a question is appropriated on SE sites when this is the first one. And thanks for the advice.

Comment: Watch your workers. Ask them. Spend a day doing the work yourself if you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US what you are looking for is assistance from [OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/) specialist. Maybe you can get [on-site consultation](https://www.osha.gov/consultation) (which is free), maybe you will have to contract a OSHA consultancy company.

Answer (score 0):

The questions you pose find their answers in the discipline of *Time and Motion Study*.

The original founding authorities are Frank Bunker Gilbreth Sr., Lillian Moller Gilbreth, and Frederick Winslow Taylor.

The last of these worthies passed away in 1972, so their writings are probably not modern enough to help you today.

Just look up the discipline by name for a list of more contemporary references.